# Insertar un svg creado en javascript en el favicon de la pagina web

Tags: javascript

He creado un svg en javascript y se que se puede agregar un favicon usando una imagen svg guardada:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg">
<link rel="alternate icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#ff8a01">
```

Sin embargo no se como insertar la imagen creada en javascript en el favicon.

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Saludos.

Código de como creo la imagen:

```
function CrearImagen(node) {
    const iconSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    const iconPath = document.createElementNS(
      'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
      'path'
    );
  
    iconSvg.setAttribute('fill', '#00FF00');
    iconSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 24 24');
    iconSvg.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
    iconSvg.classList.add('post-icon');
  
    iconPath.setAttribute(
      'd',
      'M13.828 10.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0l-4 4a4 4 0 105.656 5.656l1.102-1.101m-.758-4.899a4 4 0 005.656 0l4-4a4 4 0 00-5.656-5.656l-1.1 1.1'
    );
    iconPath.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
    iconPath.setAttribute('stroke-linejoin', 'round');
    iconPath.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');
  
    iconSvg.appendChild(iconPath);
  
    return node.appendChild(iconSvg);
  }
  function CambiarIcono(icono){
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
    if (!link) {
        link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'icon';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
    link.href = icono;
  }
```

Comment: pues ¿Ya intentaste ponerle un id y llamarlo con un querySelector y cambiarlo dinámicamente?

Comment: Esta pregunta te es de utilidad? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: @PadronRocha el problema es que la único que le puedo cambiar es el href, pero como he creado la imagen svg como variable en javascript:
const iconSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
no tengo a que href dirección dirigirlo. Saludos.

Comment: @AndresGardiol es igual que el anterior, la imagen no la he guardado en ningún lugar, la estoy creando como variable javascript por eso no puedo asignarlo en el href como esta en ese post que me comentas. Gracias.

Comment: h.setAttributeNS(null, 'href', 'http://www.google.com');
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539196/creating-svg-elements-dynamically-with-javascript-inside-html prueba esto

Comment: @PadronRocha efectivamente se puede agregar un sgv creado en javascript al cuerpo de una pagina web, pero lo que no puedo es hacer que esa imagen creada en javascript se utilice como el favicon.
Te muestro el código de un par de funciones que imprime unas cadenas en el body:
Lo pondre en el siguiente comentario por falta de caracteres.

Comment: function CrearImagen(node) {
    const iconSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    const iconPath = document.createElementNS(
      'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
      'path'
    );
    iconPath.setAttribute(
      'd',
      'M13.828 10.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0l-4 4a4 4 0 105.656 5.656l1.102-1.101m-.758-4.899a4 4 0 005.656 0l4-4a4 4 0 00-5.656-5.656l-1.1 1.1'
    );
   
    iconSvg.appendChild(iconPath);
  
    return node.appendChild(iconSvg);
  }

Comment: y con esta función para modificar el href del link rel:
  function CambiarIcono(icono){
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
    if (!link) {
        link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'icon';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
    link.href = icono;
  }

Comment: Si vas a añadir código que sea a la pregunta

Comment: Hola @RafaelAlfredoZelayaAmaya pudiste solcionar tu problema? Porque quiero hacer algo parecido pero en vez de en el favicon, en un meta tag

Comment: Lo mas que logre hacer fue esto:  <link rel=icon href='data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><text y=".9em" font-size="90"></text></svg>'>

Comment: Luego si usas el código del svg incrustado directamente el HTML lo agarra facil. Solo lo pegas.